# Independent (ASP).net Object Cache?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

I wonder, does there exist something like [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx), but for internal use?

Essentially a .net Object Cache that I'll install at a server and that speaks WCF (or something more appropriate?) with my applications - mainly ASP.net, but possibly WinForms as well.

Objects should be persistable if possible, but held in memory most of the time. In my plans, the objects are rarely updated (new ones might be added frequently, but existing ones are rarely updated) but often read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I overlooked something, Velocity seems to be able to be hosted internally. For some reason I thought I always had to use Microsofts Data Centers, but it looks like it has a server component.

I'm leaving this open in case anyone else knows another caching server, always good to know the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the HttpRuntime in IIS, your WinForms app, etc...